# Does the limit of this sequence of operators have infinitely many eigenvalues?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, spectral-theory, compact-operators

Suppose that I have a sequence of compact, injective operators $\{T_\delta\}_{\delta>0}$ on a Hilbert space $H$ such that each operator $T_\delta$ has infinitely many eigenvalues. My question is the following.

**Question:** If $T$ is a compact, injective operator on $H$ and $T_\delta\to T$ in operator norm as $\delta\to0^+$, then must $T$ have infinitely many eigenvalues?

I know that each eigenvalue of $T$ must be a limit of eigenvalues of $T_\delta$, but I am not sure how to establish the converse in the above sense. According to [Convergence of spectrum with multiplicity under norm convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235948/convergence-of-spectrum-with-multiplicity-under-norm-convergence), any $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ which is the limit point of eigenvalues of $T_\delta$ (with multiplicity taken into account) must be an eigenvalue of $T$, but I am not sure how to guarantee that infinitely many such points exist. I have mainly used Kato's book *Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators* as a reference, but I have been unable to find the right result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of a compact injective operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ (i.e. square-summable two-sided sequences) with no eigenvalues is $T$ defined by 
$$ (Tx)_i = x_{i+1}/(|i|+1)$$
This is the norm limit of compact injective operators $T_N$ where 
$$ (T_N x)_i = \cases{x_{i+1}/(|i|+1) & if $|i| \le N$\cr
                      x_{-N}/N  & if $i = N+1$\cr
                      x_{i}/(|i|+1) & otherwise\cr} $$
which have infinitely many eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you! I originally tried to construct a counterexample using this operator, but I couldn't see how to obtain the right sequence that converged in norm. This was really helpful.